# Find the first duplicated element

Tags: code-golf, array

Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to a.length, find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other number does. If there are no such elements, your program / function may result in undefined behaviour.

Example:

For `a = [2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]`, the output should be
`firstDuplicate(a) = 3`.

There are 2 duplicates: numbers 2 and 3. The second occurrence of 3 has a smaller index than the second occurrence of 2 does, so the answer is 3.

For `a = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1]`, the output should be
`firstDuplicate(a) = -1`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

BONUS: Can you solve it in O(n) time complexity and O(1) additional space complexity?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65027/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-a-anderson-find-the-first-duplicated-element).

Answer (score 17):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

*O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, O(n) space*

<sup>Saved 3 bytes thanks to @vaultah, and 3 more from @xnor!</sup>

```python
lambda l:l[map(l.remove,set(l))<0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYqxDoJAEERr7iu2hOQ0gtpcpMTEysYOKQ5ZAnE5Luuh8PUnkpA4mWbePDu5pjeJr9O7J92VlQZSlHfahrRl7Po3yhe6kKLotCv8p2kJ4cYDKgFzHE9KBJS2xg4ujERguTUO6tlffhwfaB1cTIVjxtyzWpVN/C9k1/N6l4z66fNEwn5pLOEoISnEDx0WNO@4@AI)

Comment: It looks like `lambda l:l[map(l.remove,set(l))<0]` works, even though the order of evaluation is weird.

Comment: This doesn't return `-1` when no duplicates are found without the 'footer code', does that code not count towards the bytes? I'm new to code golf, sorry if it's a basic question!

Comment: @Chris_Rands Beneath the question musicman did ask if exception is okay instead of -1 and OP said its okay and musicman's answer throws exception.

Comment: That took me a while to figure out. Well played. Getting the 0th element of l using the conditional after modifying it is really clever.

Comment: Does Python guarantee the time and space complexity of standard-library functions like set.remove?

Comment: @Draconis This is actually _list_ remove, and set construction. The whole algorithm is O(n^2): list remove is O(n) and there are O(n) iterations. It uses O(n) extra space by constructing the set and the list constructed as a result of the `map` function

Comment: @musicman523 Of course, my mistake! I see what you're doing now. Clever.

Answer (score 15):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>47</s> <s>36</s> <s>31</s> 25 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to ThePirateBay*

Returns `undefined` if no solution exists.

Time complexity: *O*(n) :-)
Space complexity: *O*(n) :-(

```js
a=>a.find(c=>!(a[-c]^=1))
```

#### How?

We keep track of already encountered values by saving them as new *properties* of the original array ***a*** by using negative numbers. This way, they can't possibly interfere with the original entries.

#### Demo

```js
let f =

a=>a.find(c=>!(a[-c]^=1))

console.log(f([2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]))
console.log(f([2, 4, 3, 5, 1]))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 1]))
```

Comment: 25 bytes: `a=>a.find(c=>!(a[-c]^=1))`

Comment: @ThePirateBay Oh, of course. Thanks!

Comment: Just notice that Objects in JavaScript may not be implemented as hash table. Time complexity of accessing keys of some object may not be O(1).

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
#/.{h=___,a_,h,a_,h}:>a&
```

Mathematica's pattern matching capability is so cool!

Returns the original `List` for invalid input.

#### Explanation

```
#/.
```

In the input, replace...

```
{h=___,a_,h,a_,h}
```

A `List` with a duplicate element, with 0 or more elements before, between, and after the duplicates...

```
... :>a
```

With the duplicate element.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Ṛœ-QṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzllHJ@sGPty56v///9FGOgrGYGSoo2Cqo2AUCwA)

#### How it works

```
Ṛœ-QṪ  Main link. Argument: A (array)

Ṛ      Yield A, reversed.
   Q   Unique; yield A, deduplicated.
 œ-    Perform multiset subtraction.
       This removes the rightmost occurrence of each unique element from reversed
       A, which corresponds to the leftmost occurrence in A.
    Ṫ  Take; take the rightmost remaining element, i.e., the first duplicate of A.
```

Comment: `œ-` removes the rightmost occurrences? TIL

Comment: This doesn't seem to return `-1` for no duplicates. Throwing an exception is okay as per OP but I'm not sure if `0` is even though it's not in the range.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
h.-Q{
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=h.-Q%7B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+5%2C+2%5D%0A%5B2%2C+4%2C+3%2C+5%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+1%2C+2%5D&debug=0)

Remove from Q the first appearance of every element in Q, then return the first element.

Comment: @LuisMendo Ok thanks. Sorry for creating confusion, I should learn to read...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder No, it's the OP's fault. That information should be in the challenge text, but just in a comment

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 35 bytes

```hs
f s(h:t)|h`elem`s=h|1<2=f(h:s)t
f[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBCsMgEAXQvaf4hCwaMIFYuin1AD2DSJPF2JEaExyXubsthbd6vMqHUmotQC58r8PJCyXaFrF8zg9jw29lqCo43/CyVMpeum4c8XznvRAqR0GKmSal1LbGDIujxFzRI8B5OKNx/Zs1bhrGty8) Crashes if no duplicate is found.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
UÞ⊍h
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiVcOe4oqNaCIsIiIsIlsyLCAxLCA0LCAxLCA0XSJd)

Takes the multi-set symmetric difference, which outputs the duplicate values in order that they occur. Outputs `0` if nothing is found.

Answer (score 4):

## Dyalog APL, <s>27</s> <s>24</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
⊢⊃⍨0⍳⍨⊢=⍴↑∪
```

Now modified to not depend on v16! [Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%u22A2%u2283%u23680%u2373%u2368%u22A2%3D%u2374%u2191%u222A%29%201%201&run)

## How? (With input **N**)

- `⊢⊃⍨...` - **N** at this index:

  - `⍴↑∪` - **N** with duplicates removed, right-padded with `0` to fit **N**
  - `⊢=` - Element-wise equality with **N**
  - `0⍳⍨` - Index of the first `0`. `

Comment: nevermind, I misread the question. not enough test cases though...

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, I also misread the question.

Comment: Looks like 36 bytes to me.

Comment: Oh god, iota underbar isn't in `⎕AV`, is it?

Comment: @Zacharý Right, Classic translates it to `⎕U2378 ` when loading. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qn/6O2CQZcjzra3TKLiktcSgv@l0c/6mp@1Luj/FHnAo1HvVvKNR@1TXzUsaocqPLQekMdoK7Y/0AN/xXAAKaPy1DBSMFYwZALImwMMqRvanCQ86PePpAePx8FS6jco85FWKUB "APL (Dyalog Classic) – Try It Online")

Comment: [You may throw an error instead of returning `¯1`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136713/find-the-first-duplicated-element?page=1&tab=votes#comment334435_136713)

Comment: That is a very clever solution. +1.

Comment: I guess I'm in the array (or at least vector) oriented way of thinking now!

Comment: In the link the solution result enclosed in () where above is not enclose; in my cellphone I not know how to run that in tio ( dialog Unicode and classic)

Comment: It's sort of like an anonymous/lambda function in JavaScript/Python. You need but parentheses to call it, but the actual function doesn't require parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
xŒQ¬$Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/i6KTAQ2tUHu5Y9P9w@6OmNf//R0cb6SgYg5GhjoKpjoJRrA6XAkjQBCwIFDEEiwBlISpNYCKmYK4RWI1JbCwA)

Returns the first duplicate, or 0 if there is no duplicate.

### Explanation

```
xŒQ¬$Ḣ  Input: array M
    $   Operate on M
 ŒQ       Distinct sieve - Returns a boolean mask where an index is truthy
          for the first occurrence of an element
   ¬      Logical NOT
x       Copy each value in M that many times
     Ḣ  Head
```

Comment: It's golfier to use indexing like this: `ŒQi0ị`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer If there are no duplicates, `i0` would return 0, where `ị` would index and return the last value of the input instead of 0.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
æ@bX ¦Y
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=5kBiWCCmWQ==&input=WzIsIDMsIDMsIDEsIDUsIDJd)

#### Explanation

```
 æ@   bX ¦ Y
UæXY{UbX !=Y}  Ungolfed
               Implicit: U = input array
UæXY{       }  Return the first item X (at index Y) in U where
     UbX         the first index of X in U
         !=Y     is not equal to Y.
               In other words, find the first item which has already occured.
               Implicit: output result of last expression
```

---

Alternatively:

```
æ@¯Y øX
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=5kCvWSD4WA==&input=WzIsIDMsIDMsIDEsIDUsIDJd)

#### Explanation

```
 æ@   ¯ Y øX
UæXY{Us0Y øX}  Ungolfed
               Implicit: U = input array
UæXY{       }  Return the first item X (at index Y) in U where
     Us0Y        the first Y items of U (literally U.slice(0, Y))
          øX     contains X.
               In other words, find the first item which has already occured.
               Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
a⊇=bh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P/FRV7ttUsb//9FGOgrGYGSoo2Cqo2AU@z8KAA)

### Explanation

```
a⊇=bh  Input is a list.
a      There is an adfix (prefix or suffix) of the input
 ⊇     and a subsequence of that adfix
  =    whose elements are all equal.
   b   Drop its first element
    h  and output the first element of the rest.
```

The adfix built-in `a` lists first all prefixes in increasing order of length, then suffixes in decreasing order of length.
Thus the output is produced by the shortest prefix that allows it, if any.
If a prefix has no duplicates, the rest of the program fails for it, since every subsequence of equal elements has length 1, and the first element of its tail doesn't exist.
If a prefix has a repeated element, we can choose the length-2 subsequence containing both, and the program returns the latter.

Comment: Another 5 bytes solution: `a⊇Ċ=h`, which only looks at length-2 subsets.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
1!`\b(\d+)\b(?<=\b\1 .*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fUDEhJkkjJkVbE0jZ29jGJMUYKuhpaf7/b6RgDISGCqYKRgA) Explanation: `\b(\d+)\b` matches each number in turn, and then the lookbehind looks to see whether the number is a duplicate; if it is the `1`st match is `!` output, rather than the count of matches. Unfortunately putting the lookbehind first doesn't seem to work, otherwise it would save several bytes. Edit: <s>Added 7 bytes to comply with the `-1` return value on no match.</s> Saved 2 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder.

Comment: For the record, the lookaround won't backtrack. This prevents this from working if you try to put it before. I've made this mistake many times, and Martin always corrects me.

Comment: [I got 30 bytes by using a lookahead instead of a lookbehind.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/f11AxISZJIyZFWxNI2dvqaSnEGMYkaXLFqXDpGv7/b6RgDISGCqYKRgA "Retina – Try It Online") Also, the rules now say you don't need to return `-1`.

Comment: @ValueInk But the correct answer for that test case is 3...

Comment: OH. I misread the challenge, whoops

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>94</s> 92 bytes

O(n) time and O(1) extra memory.

```python
def f(a):
 r=-1
 for i in range(len(a)):t=abs(a[i])-1;r=[r,i+1][a[t]<0>r];a[t]*=-1
 return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BDsIgEEXXcopZgtJEWt204kUIC1RQkoY2w7jw9EhravIXP28yL3/@0GtKXSkPHyBwJ3oGqBvFIEwIEWICdOnp@ehTvYqetLtl7ky0olEDaoMyHpQ1zpC9HK9oh6XtVwV6emMVFPKZ7i77rA3bmVZCt0ZJOEtorfzB0worUZVYtgzYHpcdf0k/Y0zEA9@IEOUL)

[Source of the algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/).

#### Explanation

The basic idea of the algorithm is to run through each element from left to right, keep track of the numbers that have appeared, and returning the number upon reaching a number that has already appeared, and return -1 after traversing each element.

However, it uses a clever way to store the numbers that have appeared without using extra memory: to store them as the sign of the element indexed by the number. For example, I can represent the fact that `2` and `3` has already appeared by having `a[2]` and `a[3]` negative, if the array is 1-indexed.

Comment: What would this do for `i` where a[i] > n?

Comment: @Downgoat read the question again.

Comment: The question says `1` to a.length but for a[i]= a.length wouldn't this go out of bounds?

Comment: @Downgoat `t=abs(a[i])-1=a.length-1`

Comment: Oh duh sorry thanks

Comment: Note from feersum: ["solution is cheating because it uses integers 1 bit larger than the input."](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39125777#39125777)

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pc7BDsIgDAbgszxFj6AskamXTXwRwgEVIgfZUrpkPj2OmZn00HxN/3b80GtIp1KePkDgTnQMUDeKQRgQopwhJvBpent05OuctLtnPotG9agNynhQ1jhD9nq8oe1rt18D0NOECbCQz/Rw2Wdt2M60Ek5rKQkXCa2VPzyvuIhaxLJ6flusP/xDuhFjIh74JkKULw) with `enumerate`

Comment: [89 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pc7BCsIwDAbgs32KHFvtwG4KsllfpPRQtcUe7EaawXz6uk0m5BA@@P9k@NCrT81lwFKePkDgTqKulGgZhB4hygliAp/Gt0dHnjvRknb3zCdRqQ61QRkPyhpnyF6PN7Tdsu3nCgboacQEWMhnerjsszZsZ2oJzTpKwllCbeUPTyvOomaxbDm/BZcf/iXtgDERD3wTIcoX) by having the initial definition of r=-1 as a default argument

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 bytes

```apl
⊃n/⍨(,≢∪)¨,\n←⎕,2⍴¯1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdLbOouMSltOD/o67mPP1HvSs0dB51LnrUsUrz0AqdmLxHbRMe9U3VMXrUu@XQekOQhv8KYADTx2Wko2AMRoY6CqY6CkZcmPImYHmgpCG6pLGOkQ4YAwA)

`2⍴¯1` negative one **r**eshaped into a length-two list

`⎕,` get input (mnemonic: console box) and prepend to that

`n←` store that in *n*

`,\` prefixes of *n* (lit. cumulative concatenation)

`(`…`)¨` apply the following tacit function to each prefix

`,` [is] the ravel (just ensures that the prefix is a list)

`≢` different from

`∪` the unique elements[?] (i.e. is does the prefix have duplicates?)

`n/⍨` use that to filter *n* (removes all elements until the first for which a duplicate was found)

`⊃` pick the first element from that

Comment: Wow, you got beat three times. Still, +1. And can you add an explanation of how this works?

Comment: @Zacharý Apparently I just needed to get the ball rolling. Here you go.

Comment: @Zacharý Eventually, [I managed to beat them all](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137497/43319).

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 13 bytes

```perl6
*.repeated[0]
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszZVbqaCWlllUXKKbUlqQk5mcWJKqYPtfS68otSAVyE6JNoj9D1blkKhgq2Cko2AMRoY6CqY6CkbWXMWJlQpo@jUcEjWtFZQVjLnA@pIg@kzA@oCaDHFoSgJr8svM@Q8A)

---

### Explanation

- The `*` is in a Term position so the whole statement is a [WhateverCode](https://docs.perl6.org/type/WhateverCode) lambda.
- The `.repeated` is a method that results in every value except for the first time each value was seen.

  ```perl6
  say [2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3].repeated.perl; # (3, 3, 2, 3).Seq
  #   (      3, 3,       2, 3).Seq
  ```
- `[0]` just returns the first value in the [Seq](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq).
  If there is no value [Nil](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Nil) is returned.
  ([Nil](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Nil) is the base of the [Failure](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Failure) types, and all types are their own undefined value, so [Nil](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Nil) different than an undefined value in most other languages)

---

Note that since the [implementation of `.repeated`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/51e59eeb5e48917ed3e825947989f91a219ce2cc/src/core/Any-iterable-methods.pm#L1595-L1628) generates a [Seq](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq) that means it doesn't start doing any work until you ask for a value, and it only does enough work to generate what you ask for.
So it would be easy to argue this has at worst *O(n)* time complexity, and at best *O(2)* time complexity if the second value is a repeat of the first.
Similar can probably be said of memory complexity.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
,&_1{~~:i.0:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kpBRy3esLquzipTz8CKiys1OSNfQcM6TVPNTsFIwRgIDRVMgSxrIDYB8kwVDP//BwA)

### Explanation

```
,&_1{~~:i.0:  Input: array M
      ~:      Nub-sieve
          0:  The constant 0
        i.    Find the index of the first occurrence of 0 (the first duplicate)
,&_1          Append -1 to M
    {~        Select the value from the previous at the index of the first duplicate
```

Answer (score 3):

### APL, 15

```
{⊃⍵[(⍳⍴⍵)~⍵⍳⍵]}
```

Seems like we can return 0 instead of -1 when there are no duplicates, (thanks Adám for the comment). So 3 bytes less.

A bit of description:

```
⍵⍳⍵         search the argument in itself: returns for  each element the index of it's first occurrence
(⍳⍴⍵)~⍵⍳⍵   create a list of all indexes, remove those found in ⍵⍳⍵; i.e. remove all first elements
⊃⍵[...]     of all remaining elements, take the first. If the array is empty, APL returns zero
```

For reference, old solution added -1 to the list at the end, so if the list ended up empty, it would contain -1 instead and the first element would be -1.

```
{⊃⍵[(⍳⍴⍵)~⍵⍳⍵],¯1}
```

Try it on [tryapl.org](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2283%u2375%5B%28%u2373%u2374%u2375%29%7E%u2375%u2373%u2375%5D%7D2%203%203%201%205%202&run)

Comment: [You may return a zero instead of `¯1`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136713/find-the-first-duplicated-element?page=1&tab=votes#comment334435_136713), so `{⊃⍵[(⍳⍴⍵)~⍵⍳⍵]}` should do.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>56 44 38</s> 32 bytes

```
for(;!${$argv[++$x]}++;);echo$x;
```

Run like this:

```
php -nr 'for(;!${$argv[++$x]}++;);echo$x;' -- 2 3 3 1 5 2;echo
> 3
```

## Explanation

```
for(
  ;
  !${                 // Loop until current value as a variable is truthy
    $argv[++$x]       // The item to check for is the next item from input
  }++;                // Post increment, the var is now truthy
);
echo $x;              // Echo the index of the duplicate.
```

## Tweaks

- Saved 12 bytes by using variables instead of an array
- Saved 6 bytes by making use of the "undefined behavior" rule for when there is no match.
- Saved 6 bytes by using post-increment instead of setting to 1 after each loop

## Complexity

As can be seen from the commented version of the code, the time complexity is linear `O(n)`. In terms of memory, a maximum of `n+1` variables will be assigned. So that's `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for not using a weird encoding. But you should add the `error_reporting` option to the byte count (or use `-n`, which is free).

Comment: We've been here before. PHP notices and warnings are ignorable. I might as well pipe them to `/dev/null`, which is the same.

Comment: I tend to remember the wrong comments. :) Isn´t this O(n)?

Comment: Yes it's linear

Comment: How is that `O(1)` for additional space? You're literally assigning a new variable per `n`, which is `O(n)`

Comment: @Xanderhall, I might have misunderstood, but doesn't the question say *additional* space? I took that to mean `O(n)` was assumed to be necessary anyway.

Comment: The storage for the initial list has`O(n)` space complexity, yes. However, if you're say, storing every single value in a separate list to check if you've passed them, that's `O(n)` additional space complexity. What you're doing is effectively the same, but without the 'list' construct. In your worst case (say, `[1, 2, ..., n, 1]` you'll end up with `n` variables created additionally, which is `O(n)` space complexity

Comment: @Xanderhall The list is actually even worse than `O(n)`, its `O(n log n)` because each number requires at most `O(log n)` bits to store and there are n of them. I don't understand php so I can't comment on this answers complexity directly but  if it stores up to n+1 values that can be as large as n then it has `O(n log n)` space complexity.  It only has `O(n)` space complexity if each variable is some fixed number of bits.

Comment: @WheatWizard, not at all. They are INTs (basically booleans) that will never be anything other than `0`, `1` or `2`. And the `2` case is not used, it's just a simplification of the code

Comment: @Xanderhall, I removed the statement as I'm not sure now what was meant.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

As per [the new rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136713/find-the-first-duplicated-element/136797?noredirect=1#comment334435_136713), throws an error if no duplicates exist.

```apl
⊢⊃⍨⍬⍴⍳∘≢~⍳⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3y2zqLjEpbTgUduER12LHnU1P@pd8ah3zaPeLY96Nz/qmPGoc1EdiNW74v9/BTCA6VAw0lEwBiNDHQVTHQUjLjR5Yx0jHTDmwtRoAtYI1GUIAA)

`⍳⍨` the indices of the first occurrence of each element

`~` removed from

`⍳∘≢` of all the indices

`⍬⍴` reshape that into a scalar (gives zero if no data is available)

`⊃⍨` use that to pick from (gives error on zero)

`⊢` the argument

Comment: Well, yeah, when the rules are changed, of course you can beat them all!

Comment: Well, I tied you.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
*(~':?',\)#
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LSqFO3slfXidFU5uJKi9YwUjAGQhMFUwUjzViIAIgDEoQLQOTNNGMBn9wMqw==)

```
*(~':?',\)#
 (       )#   keep the elements where the left function returns true
              (when applied to the whole array):
       ,\       prefixes
     ?'         uniquify each
  ~':           is it the same as previous?
*             first element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
&=Rsqf1)
```

Gives an error (without output) if no duplicate exists.

Try at [**MATL Online!**](https://matl.io/?code=%26%3DRsqf1%29&inputs=%5B2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+5%2C+2%5D&version=20.2.2)

#### Explanation

```
&=   % Implict input. Matrix of all pairwise equality comparisons
R    % Keep the upper triangular part (i.e. set lower part to false)
s    % Sum of each column
q    % Subtract 1
f    % Indices of nonzero values
1)   % Get first. Gives an error is there is none. Implictly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
(*/{_1,~i.&0)@~:
```

#### How?

```
(*/{_1,~i.&0)@~:

             @~: returns the nub sieve which is a vector with 1 for the first occurrence of an element in the argument and 0 otherwise

        i.&0     returns the first index of duplication

    _1,~         appends _1 to the index

 */              returns 0 with duplicates (product across nub sieve)

     {           select _1 if no duplicates, otherwise return the index
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
(x=scan())[duplicated(x)][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6PCtjg5MU9DUzM6pbQgJzM5sSQ1RaNCMzbaMPa/KZcxEBpymXIZcf0HAA)

Comment: I think you can now return `NA` for missing values since the spec has changed; so `(x=scan())[duplicated(x)][1]` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 34 bytes

```
c((x=scan())[duplicated(x)],-1)[1]
```

Cut a few characters off the answer from @djhurio, don't have enough reputation to comment though.

Comment: oh...I didn't see this answer; this is good for the prior spec when missing values required `-1` but with the new spec, I managed to golf it down even more. This is still solid and it's a different approach from the way he did it, so I'll give you a +1!

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <strike>82</strike> <strike>78</strike> <strike>76 bytes</strike> No longer viable, <strike>75</strike> <strike>67</strike> 64 bytes below in edit

As a lambda function:

```java8
a->{Set<Long>s=new HashSet<>();for(long i:a)if(!s.add(i))return i;return-1;}
```

Probably can be made much smaller, this was very quick.

#### Explanation:

```java8
a->{                                //New lambda function with 'a' as input
    Set<Long>s=new HashSet<>();     //New set
    for(long i:a)                   //Iterate over a
        if(!s.add(i))               //If can't add to s, already exists
            return i;               //Return current value
        return-1;                   //No dupes, return -1
}
```

## *Edit*

<strike>75</strike> <strike>67</strike> 64 bytes using the negation strategy:

```java8
a->{int i=0,j;while((a[j=Math.abs(a[i++])-1]*=-1)<0);return++j;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBbsIwDD03X5FjO9yoSaGASjlNk3bgxBFxyCCFdCWtGpcJIb69Swubpm1RIsfPst/zK@RZhlWtTLF/7/SprhqkhcNYi7pkeWt2qCvDXh6flJC6fSv1ju5KaS1dSW3I1SPeA7Uo0YVzpff05Gr@GhttDpstlc3BBsS7EvrroLLocxAwhnh4SZASz/uGe3ACCUxhBnPgEXAOXACPgY@BT4AnwKfAZ8DnICIQrkeAiEGMQUxAJCCmIGYg5hBHEHOI3cjY3Z7lRv5I1wZprs3@ua2V75JBejMo97wvGxZDAeirQXVQzZLmNKOdDJfXvl1nERTpx1GXyvflpshWEo9MvlmX6NFoG4R8@5SFPFhEQdoobBszGhXprev3vuc0Z7Kuy4vfc/8vdPB4cMlxMsZ65fahc32xqE6sapHVzn8sjf9zJxvcZ95I9wk)

(-3 bytes thanks to @Nevay)

#### Explanation:

```java8
a->{                                         //New lambda expression with 'a' as input
    int i=0,j;                               //Initialise i and declare j
    while((a[j=Math.abs(a[i++])-1]*=-1)<0);  //Negate to keep track of current val until a negative is found
    return++j;                               //Return value
}
```

Loops over the array, negating to keep track. If no dupes, just runs over and throws an error.

Both of these work on O(n) time and O(n) space complexity.

Comment: It's worth noting that this will need to be assigned to a lambda returning `Number`, since `i` is a `long` and `-1` is an `int`.

Comment: @Jakob Not necessary, -1 being an int will automatically be cast to a long without explicitly specifying the cast

Comment: It will cast implicitly to `long`, but not to `Long` as required for the lambda to be assigned to a `Function`. Did you test it? Regardless, that solution can be replaced with your new one.

Comment: You can use raw types `Set s=new HashSet();` to save 7 bytes. (Besides: afaik the import of `java.util.*;` has to be included into the byte count -> +19 bytes.) The return statement can be `return++j`, the if-statement can be removed `a->{int i=0,j;for(;(a[j=Math.abs(a[i++])-1]*=-1)<0;);return++j;}` (-3 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

### Dyalog APL Classic, 18 chars

Only works in `⎕IO←0`.

```
     w[⊃(⍳∘≢~⍳⍨)w←¯1,⎕]
```

Remove from the list of indices of the elements of the argument with a prepended "-1" the list indices of its nub and then pick the first of what's left. If after the removal there only remains an empty vector, its first element is by definition 0 which is used to index the extended argument producing the desired -1.

Comment: Um... what's with the random leading spaces? +1 for outgolfing me by *one* byte.

Comment: [You may throw an error instead of returning `¯1`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136713/find-the-first-duplicated-element?page=1&tab=votes#comment334435_136713), so you can remove `¯1,` and use `⎕IO←1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>28</s> 36 bytes

Misunderstood the challenge the first time. `O(n)` time, `O(n)` space.

```ruby
->a{d={};a.find{|e|b=d[e];d[e]=1;b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cusTrFtrrWOlEvLTMvpbomtSbJNiU6NdYaRNgaWifV1v4vz8jMSVVITy0p5ipQSItOLUvMUVCJj@VKzUv5H22ko2AMRoY6CqY6CkaxXCAhE7AQkG8YCwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>65</s> <s>117</s> 109 bytes

Previous 65 byte solution:

```java
r->{for(int a,b=0,z,i=0;;b=a)if((a=b|1<<(z=r[i++]))==b)return z;}
```

New solution. 19 bytes are included for `import java.math.*;`

*-8 bytes thanks to @Nevay*

```java
r->{int z,i=0;for(BigInteger c=BigInteger.ZERO;c.min(c=c.setBit(z=r[i++]))!=c;);return z;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNb9swDD3Hv4K7SasjdCm2i@sA6z6AHooB7U4retBs2ZNnS4ZEB02K/PaUkuO5xVLAMCW@R@mJj43cyKXtlWnKvwfd9dYhNJQTncQ/4krX1wZVrVyWvAQH1K347Jzc@hNANZgCtTXi@3FxguPRKdkJOv0urt6mTHjSD79bXUDRSu/hRmqTPCWLY9KjRAobq0voCGJUpU19/wDS1Z4nC6IuUHlkqxQu4vchhY8prHg2IZQYwfCf0xf/pSvrgGmDoCGH8xQaCquMdpfwicLZGYdwXSy/laZWrIl1iwbeByYt9wl9pN7pjUT1Sv5cFa7weqdeyh@7IWzF/rVOuMD@0lqvyvCIWJLCjBN5SnNRtRJvZP/TEs7GFi/XY@QCbTSV8aCXNL6tMIgTQgCFqb13W4@KbhtQUJXB1rBxROjY0Q4W2bEXJ8iVNuXXoSc76cJrU6rHmT9qeeV16M7pEnLdPR5FTSN4GfOxK2Gc11CRaQe3XD@Fc3apzs8z8pXNEw9FPm/Er2@3P7JCdDRaRV4Ir/BKI9vl7p78fuD8XV5kPHMKB2dgl@0P4ZHHbSVk37dbRqLiU/bJ4Rk)

## Edit

The algorithm in my original program was fine, but the static size of the datatype used meant that it broke fairly quickly once the size went above a certain threshold.

I have changed the datatype used in the calculation to increase the memory limit of the program to accommodate this (using `BigInteger` for arbitrary precision instead of `int` or `long`). However, this makes it debatable whether or not this counts as `O(1)` space complexity.

I will leave my explanation below intact, but I wish to add that I now believe it is impossible to achieve `O(1)` space complexity without making some assumptions.

## Proof

Define `N` as an integer such that `2 <= N` .

Let `S` be a list representing a series of random integers `[x{1}, ..., x{N}]`, where `x{i}` has the constraint `1 <= x{i} <= N`.

The time complexity (in Big-O notation) required to iterate through this list exactly once per element is `O(n)`

The challenge given is to find the first duplicated value in the list. More specifically, we are searching for the first value in `S` that is a duplicate of a previous item on the list.

Let `p` and `q` be the positions of two elements in the list such that `p < q` and `x{p} == x{q}`. Our challenge becomes finding the smallest `q` that satisfies those conditions.

The obvious approach to this problem is to iterate through S and check if our `x{i}` exists in another list `T`:
    If `x{i}` does not exist in `T`, we store it in `T`.
    If `x{i}` does exist in `T`, it is the first duplicate value and therefore the smallest `q`, and as such we return it.
This space efficiency is `O(n)`.

In order to achieve `O(1)` space complexity while maintaining `O(n)` time complexity, we have to store unique information about each object in the list in a finite amount of space. Because of this, the only way any algorithm could perform at `O(1)` space complexity is if:
    1. N is given an upper bound corresponding to the memory required to store the maximum number of possible values for a particular finite datatype.
    2. The re-assignment of a single immutable variable is not counted against the complexity, only the number of variables (a list being multiple variables).
    3. (Based on other answers) The list is (or at least, the elements of the list are) mutable, and the datatype of the list is preset as a signed integer, allowing for changes to be made to elements further in the list without using additional memory.

1 and 3 both require assumptions and specifications about the datatype, while 2 requires that only the number of variables be considered for the calculation of space complexity, rather than the size of those variables. If none of these assumptions are accepted, it would be impossible to achieve both `O(n)` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity.

## Explanation

Whoo boy, this one took <s>an embarrassingly long time to think up</s> a bit of brain power.

So, going for the bonus is difficult. We need both to operate over the entire list exactly once **and** track which values we've already iterated over without additional space complexity.

Bit manipulation solves those problems. We initialize our `O(1)` 'storage', a pair of integers, then iterate through the list, OR-ing the ith bit in our first integer and storing that result to the second.

For instance, if we have `1101`, and we perform an OR operation with `10`, we get `1111`. If we do another OR with `10`, we still have `1101`.

Ergo, once we perform the OR operation and end up with the same number, we've found our duplicate. No duplicates in the array causes the program to run over and throw an exception.

Comment: Also, your second test includes the number 100, but thats impossible since the array itself is only 5 long

Comment: Also, [this](https://tio.run/##bVHLasMwEDxbX6GjTKfCkvPEcaBQCj301GPpQU7koNSRjSyHPJpvT5VXoTQXaTW7szs7Wqq1eqwbbZfzr6NZNbXzdBkw3nlT8Sfn1LbNyL9E2dmZN7XlL9fgTk3rnVYr/mr9@znKCGm6ojIzOqtU29I3ZSzZRyS6oq1XPlzr2szpKuRYoBm7@Pikyi3amER7EkVet54JSKTooY8BhhhhDJFACAgJkUL0IPoQA4ghxAhiDJlABo6ETCF7kH3IAeQQcgQ5RpogFUhDy8ANR5yR6ED@6TLW09LY@XPXBFR5/WrnesMCHBS6zVXfzY/JGQcN2@uFdlNa0pwe3eN0X9buRKIKRZ5gB5MnWVbkKjYlYyovvsVkwna5@zAPD59xnOdF7LTvnKW77HAM2qLrs@SqaaotC7N/FTuzDsr@WHl2LAzknJ92uBn5vm29XvG68zywrK8su/w29/XFeHauPvW@V3zfikv9gRzI8Qc) fails since an int doesn't have enough storage.

Comment: @SchoolBoy Good catch. My only problem is that there doesn't seem to be any upper limit on the size of the array, so I can't realistically change my code to solve memory issues.

Comment: @Xanderhall True, but i feel like 32 (or if you use a long, 64) numbers is too little :p. Either way, imposing a limit on the input, and then allocating the maximum memory needed and calling it O(1) memory is just a cheat. It is still O(n) since if the size of the input increased, so would this upper bound to the memory. Which is also why I think it is impossible to create an O(n) O(1) algorithm

Comment: @Xanderhall P.S. I'm getting close to your 65, I'm at 67 bytes :p

Comment: You don't need `d`, the if-statement can be removed `r->{int z,i=0;for(BigInteger c=BigInteger.ZERO;!c.equals(c=c.setBit(z=r[i++])););return z;}` (91+19 bytes). If you don't mind to depend on the implementation rather than on the api, you can use `c.min(c=c.setBit(z=r[i++]))!=c` instead of `#equals` to save another byte.

Comment: I may not be fully understanding the final part about bit ORing, but just because your current OR product ORed with this new number is the same, doesn't mean it's been in your list before.  For example, if your list was [12, 4, 12], you would do `1100 | 0100 = 1100` but 4 isn't a duplicate.  Even the example `[2, 4, 3, 5, 1]` fails since by the time you get to `5` your OR product will be `010 | 100 | 011 = 111`, which when ORed with `101` is still `111`.  Maybe I'm just not understanding what you're trying to say...

Comment: You're not ORing the `nth` number found in the list with the storage, you're ORing the `nth` byte in the storage. ie: in `[1, 2, 3, 2, 3]`, you would get `001` (first bit), `011`(second bit), `111`(third bit), `111`(second bit again), then 2 would be returned.

Comment: I would say that although the input is not specifically limited, imposing a limit like 32 on it is harsh, but using longs or ints instead of BigIntegers should be fine

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can golf `import java.math.*;BigInteger c=BigInteger.ZERO;` to `java.math.BigInteger t=null,c=t.ZERO;` for -11 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
←Ṡ-u
```

Returns `0` if no input contains no duplicate, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qKmx6Nzi8v@P2iY83LlAt/T////RRjoKxmBkqKNgqqNgFAsA)

#### Explanation

```
←Ṡ-u  -- takes a list X as input & returns 0 or first duplicate
 Ṡ-   -- compute X - ...
   u  --       ...   deduplicate X
←     -- get first element or 0 if empty
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f x=head$x\\nub x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrTaHCNiM1MUWlIiYmrzRJoeK/rq4CSEBPQyMmRtNGyw4oqsmVm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioKKQFm2oY6RjDIRAOvY/AA) For an input `x = [2,3,3,1,5,2]`, `nub x` removes duplicates `[2,3,1,5]` and `x\\nub x` removes the elements of `nub x` from x, thus keeping the duplicates `[3,2]`. `head` returns the first element of hat list.

---

Point-free is the same byte count: `head.((\\)<*>nub)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-1`, 4 bytes

```
pƆᵗf
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpKuoVLsgqWlJWm6FssLjrU93Do9bUlxUnIxVGzBTaVoIx0FYzAy1FEw1VEwiuUCCZmAhYB8w1iIUgA)

```
pƆᵗf
p       Find a prefix of the input
 Ɔ      Split it into the last element and the rest
  ᵗf    Check if the last element is in the rest, and return it if it is
```

`-1` prints the first possible result, or nothing if there is no result.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.ΔkNÊ
```

Outputs `-1` if there are no duplicated items, like in the challenge examples.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79yUbL/DXf//RxvpGAOhoY6pjlEsAA) or [verify both test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeXhCYdW/tc7N@XQuuJsv8Nd/2t1/kdHG@kYA6GhjqmOUawOkGcC5JnqGMbGAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.Δ     # Find the first element in the (implicit) input-list where the following is
       # truthy, or -1 if none are truthy:
  k    #  Get the first index of the current integer in the (implicit) input-list
   NÊ  #  Check whether it's NOT equal to the current find_first index
       # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: What was wrong with the original "Outputs an empty string if there are no duplicates" 4-byte version?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen It outputs the first integer that occurs more than once, instead of the first result that occurred before. So for the first test case (`[2,3,3,1,5,2]`) it would incorrectly result in `2` instead of `3`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying.  (Not that I ought to have been skulking around in the edit history...)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 145 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;a=>{var d=a.Where(n=>a.Count(t=>t==n)>1);return d.Select((n,i)=>new{n,i}).FirstOrDefault(o=>d.Take(o.i).Contains(o.n))?.n??-1;}
```

Probably a lot shorter way to do this in C# with a simple loop but I wanted to try it with Linq.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9Na8MwDIbv@RU62pAa0m2nzO5ho6eNjXXQQ@nBJCozS@TNVjpGyG/P3AT2Ab3sxViSpUeWqrhoPfmRbIvxzVYIm8/I2Ko7R@9Zn0FS1dgY4XHy55eTIlt2FRy9q@HeOhLyO/VTdNK6o@raEe/2OSRj4AAaRqtNf7QBam3V9gUDCtLGqhvfEQvWhrUmaQpZBuQuENRqgw1WLATlTmpD@NEnb5Bq7ULkh3CLB9s1LLw2tXq2ryi8cjI1JE7TxRSRlCtFq9WiKIexzP4Mmcqib1Btg2NMu6M4iPTFbg89LHO4mE6Rw1UOSxikLP9DX050QosZPcs@oa0n9FfvIZvvYfwC)

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
namespace System.Linq
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Func<int[], int> f = a =>
            {
                var d = a.Where(n => a.Count(t => t == n) > 1);
                return d.Select((n, i) => new { n, i }).FirstOrDefault(o => d.Take(o.i).Contains(o.n))?.n ?? -1;
            };

            Console.WriteLine(f(new[] { 2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2 }));
            Console.WriteLine(f(new[] { 2, 4, 3, 5, 1 }));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##lU9NS8QwED2bX/GOCdtd7KqntHsRPK0gePBQegg1rYHdSfNRRUp/e02XtZ59DMzMm/eYmSZsz5bsPARDHV6/Q9RnyVhzUiHgBSNDQogqmgaf1rzjWRniIfokr2oo3wVxVS14GqgpDMWqzpDSAW0iUGIVLFgbxmZVHsbWep7EcOWtdIXaHTV18UPCbTbid9anWV842SfOtFxVri5LVfW18DoOnrAw8lpvcznNN3Ld82gp2JPevXkT9dGQ5stZnPRXemHEPsPdJfIMDxn2mIT4j/n@Yk7O/M85sWn@AQ) is the simple loop version. But I like the Linq version much more.

Comment: @LiefdeWen Post it as an answer :) Though I do usually like Linq better too :) Might be able to get it shorter with Linq too but I'm now sure.

Comment: Nah, this question is overpopulated and I would rather you get the up-votes for this question.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>78</s> 69 bytes

```hs
 fst.foldl(\(i,a)(j,x)->(last$i:[j|i<0,elem x a],x:a))(-1,[]).zip[1..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchNDoIwEAbQvaf4FizaZGgs6oYAN/AEpYtJoLE4/ERYEOPdq5K81Xvw@uxFUqgTwrqZMEsnqlWRWKuBdp03Snjdsli64ROrM/XSj9jBnvaStVa5Jee1ecfFWWN8GjlOqNHNJwAjL3eoVvJmecVpywJEw7mCcDlYwo1QeML/rsf9wnqfvg)

*Saved 9 bytes thanks to @nimi*

A basic path through the list. If the current element has not yet been seen (`i<0`) and is in the accumulator list (`elem x a`) then store the current index. Else, keep the index -1. In any case, add the current element to the accumulator list.

**EDIT**: I did not read the question carefully enough: this code outputs the index of the second element of a duplicate element.

Comment: You can use the ["Shorter Conditional"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96371/34531) from our ["Tips for golfing in Haskell"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19255/34531): `\ ... ->(last$i:[j|i<0,elem x a],x:a)`. Also: no need for the `f=`, because unnamed functions are allowed.

Comment: @nimi thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

## PROLOG (SWI), 54 + 3 = 57 bytes

```
f([H|_],L,H):-member(H,L).
f([H|T],L,X):-f(T,[H|L],X).
```

+3 bytes because it requires an empty list as its second argument:

```
f([5,3,2,1,2,3,5],[],X)
```

will unify X to the first duplicate value in the list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P00j2qMmPlbHR8dD00o3NzU3KbVIw0PHR1OPCywVApKKAEqlaYToAPk@sUCe3n97XR/baFMdYx0jHUMgNtYxjdVJ0/DRiQZJ65QXZZakasAZSjpKQOPAWox0FIzByFBHwVRHwYiQrv8A)

Here's the basic algorithm: we have the list to parse, and an accumulator list that starts empty. For each element in the list: pop that element. If it is in the accumulator, return the element. Else, put it in the accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <strike>71</strike> 65 bytes

Returns `None` if there is no duplicate element

**Edit:** -6 bytes thanks to [@musicman523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69054/musicman523)

```python
def f(n):
 for a in n:
	u=-abs(a)
	if n[u]<0:return-u
	n[u]=-n[u]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsMgEMbxWZ/iRgWFxraLNE8iDib1qMslGB3y9DYXOL7hB//bz/bbyI3xzQioSHsJuFVIUAjIS9Fnm5ZDJS1FQaDQ4@fha269ku1SMMyWd3C2piNzGYIz8LxvMvA24KIBttdtF0wxXt/3WqgpVNxpPf4)

**O(n)** time complexity, **O(n)** space complexity, **O(1)** auxiliary space.

As the input list uses **O(n)** space, the space complexity is bound by this. Meaning we cannot have a lower space complexity than **O(n)**

Does modify the original list, if this is not allowed we could do it in the same complexity with [129 bytes](https://tio.run/##NU5BCsIwEDw3r9hjAim0VS/R@JGQQ9REA7It2@bg62O2Iiy7M8PMsMtne8041fqICZJETXZQRkCaCQJkBDSiK7YPt1UGdRZdToCu@Otg@Niet@jie42GrCPdF@/oMvpfReYKCviM8h1RolItlr3lOgZKAMWtUDNV9t/DGjni3KThsM@o4aRh8hpYO@5aE0bv22cLZdxkkpxT6s93Vr8)

## Explanation

Since every element is greater than 0 and less than or equal to the size of the list, the list has for each element a, an element on index a - 1 (0 indexed). We exploit this by saying that if the element at index i is negative, we have seen it before.

For each element a in the list n, we let u be negative the absolute value of a. *(We let it be negative since python can index lists with negative indices, and we would otherwise need to do* `u=abs(a)-1`) If the element at index u in the list is negative, we have seen it before and can therefore return -u *(to get the absolute value of a, as all elements are positive)*. Else we set the element at index u to be negative, to remember that we have seen an element of value a before.

Comment: Nice job! [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsMgEMbxWZ/iRgWFxraLNE8iDib1qMslGB3y9DYXOL7hB//bz/bbyI3xzQioSHsJuFVIUAjIS9Fnm5ZDJS1FQaDQ4@fha269ku1SMMyWd3C2piNzGYIz8LxvMvA24KIBttdtF0wxXt/3WqgpVNxpPf4)

Comment: Are you sure this is **O(1)** in memory?  You are still using **n** bits of memory to store what numbers have already been visited, even though the bits are in the sign.  It seems to me that this is **O(n)** in disguise

Comment: Technically this uses **O(n)** space - the n sign bits. If the array can only hold values between `1` and `n`, like how it was given, then it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: This really just comes down to the representation you choose for the numbers. If unsigned numbers are used, then this is **O(n)** auxiliary space. If signed numbers are used, then the sign bit is already there, meaning **O(1)** auxiliary space.

Comment: I agree with you there.  I personally would let you slide using signed integers as long as you didn't *use* the sign bit, it should be about the algorithm not the technicalities of the system.  That being said I do think if you are going to use the sign bits you have to count them.  I think this answer is pretty clever.  If I any votes left today I would upvote it to counteract the downvote.

Comment: I think `n[u]*=-1` would work to save two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ŒQi0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opMBMg////0cb6SiY6CgY6yiY6igYxgIA)

In case that all elements are unique, this returns `0` (undefined behavior).

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 12 bytes

**Solution:**

```
*<0W^*:'1_'=
```

**Example:**

```
*<0W^*:'1_'=2 3 3 1 5 2
3
```

**Explanation:**

Returns first item in the list for unique lists otherwise returns first dupe:

```
*<0W^*:'1_'= / the solution
           = / group the list, e.g. 2 3 1 5!(0 5;1 2;,3;,4)
        1_'  / drop first from each value, e.g. 2 3 1 5!(,5;,2;`long$();`long$())
     *:'     / first (*:) each ('), e.g. 2 3 1 5!5 2 0N 0N
  0W^        / fill (^) nulls with infinity (0W), e.g. 2 3 1 5!5 2 0W 0W
 <           / sort keys based on values, e.g. 3 2 1 5
*            / take the first, e.g. 3
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 21 bytes

```
/o/
\iHQ@/w].(?~!&WK?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/X58rJtMj0EG/PFZPw75OUS3c2/7/fyMdEx1jHTMgNtQx1TECAA)

#### Explanation

The main idea is to store each value we've encountered on the tape and then use the search command to check whether the current value has already been written to the tape. It's important here that the tape is initially completely filled with `-1`s.

```
/      Switch to Ordinal mode.
i      Read all input as a string.
/      Switch back to Cardinal mode.
H      Take the absolute value of the top stack element. This doesn't really do
       anything to the numbers, because they're all positive anyway, but
       it forces Alice to convert the input string to individual integer
       values it contains, thus splitting the string.
/      Switch to Ordinal mode.
Q      Reverse the stack so that the first input is on top.
/      Switch back to Cardinal mode.
w      Push the current IP position onto the return address stack. This marks
       the beginning of the main loop.
         Call the current value on top of the stack X.
  ]      Advance the tape head (unnecessary on the first iteration, but
         we need to do it between iterations).
  .      Duplicate X.
  (      Search left of the tape head for X. If X isn't found nothing happens
         and we remain on a -1. Otherwise, the tape head jumps to that
         earlier occurrence.
  ?      Retrieve the value under the tape head. If X is new, this will be
         -1. Otherwise, it will be X. Call this value Y.
  ~!     Store X in the current cell.
  &W     Discard Y values from the return address stack. If Y is negative,
         this does nothing, otherwise it discards the one return address we
         have there, terminating the loop.
$K     If the return address is still there, jump back to the w to process 
       the next element. Otherwise continue.
?      Retrieve X.
\      Switch to Ordinal mode.
o      Output the result.
H      Trim, does nothing.
@      Terminate the program.
```

I've got an alternative solution at the same byte count:

```
/o/
\iHQ@/w.!(]?h$WK[?
```

I also had a solution where I used the tape as a lookup table, storing at each index `X` whether `X` had already been seen in the sequence, but it ended up being a byte longer (it's conceptually easier, but moving the tape head to position `X` from an arbitrary positive position requires five bytes with `q&[&]`).

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 22 bytes

```
00000000: 33c0 9992 d792 d7d7 3bc2 75f7 33c0 d792  3.......;.u.3...
00000010: d73b c275 f9c3                           .;.u..
```

Listing:

```
33 C0       XOR  AX, AX         ; AL = 0, starting hare position
99          CWD                 ; DL = 0, starting tortoise position
        L1:
92          XCHG AX, DX         ; swap t/h in AL
D7          XLAT                ; tortoise crawl to next
92          XCHG AX, DX         ; swap t/h in AL
D7          XLAT                ; hare hops
D7          XLAT                ; hare hops again 
3B C2       CMP  AX, DX         ; did they land on same element?
75 F7       JNZ  L1             ; loop if not
33 C0       XOR  AX, AX         ; start tortoise at beginning to find first index match
        L2:
D7          XLAT                ; tortoise crawls
92          XCHG AX, DX         ; swap t/h in AL
D7          XLAT                ; hare hops
3B C2       CMP  AX, DX         ; did they land on same element?
75 F9       JNZ  L2             ; loop if not
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

The old Tortoise and Hare (cycle detection) algorithm... using as many 1 byte opcodes as possible.

- Time complexity: O(2n), linear
- Space complexity: O(1) (uses no additional  memory - all work done in CPU registers)

As a callable function, input pointer to list at `[BX]`, output index in `AL`.

Test results using DOS DEBUG:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 21 bytes

```
[ duplicates ?first ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxCsJAEEX7nOKfQNhoIGqhndjYSCqxWNYJLC7rZmZSiOTs6yi/ee8Vf/RBX1yH6/ly2kFIBYVJ9V04ZsWTOFOyPs2UAwn2TfNBi7XNoTNazDfYGjlrnVH/b63Vnzss9YbHXFIMXu3hMEYWxb0qxyNWgpDIc/0C)

Returns `f` in case the input has no duplicates. This is idiomatic for Factor rather than `-1`. Let me know if that's not allowed and I can fix it (i.e. make it much longer).

- `duplicates` Return only the elements that repeat in a sequence (in order).
- `?first` Return the first element of a sequence or `f` if the sequence is empty.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 39 bytes

```
Prompt A
ʟA
Ans(1+sum(not(cumSum(seq(I≠1+sum(not(cumSum(Ans=Ans(I)))),I,1,dim(Ans
```

Output is stored in `Ans` and is displayed at the end. Throws an error if there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](https://gema.sourceforge.net/), 46 characters

```
<N>=@cmpn{${$0;};;;;$0@end}@set{$0;1}
?=
\Z=-1
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.1$ gema '<N>=@cmpn{${$0;};;;;$0@end}@set{$0;1};?=;\Z=-1' <<< '[2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]'
3

bash-5.1$ gema '<N>=@cmpn{${$0;};;;;$0@end}@set{$0;1};?=;\Z=-1' <<< '[2, 4, 3, 5, 1]'
-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/38bPztYhObcgr1qlWsXAutYaCFQMHFLzUmodilNLQGKGtVz2tlwxUba6hv//RxvpKBiDkaGOgqmOglEsAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
{x@({+/y=x}':x)?1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qucNCo1tavtK2oVbeq0LQ3rOXiSovWMFIwBkITBVMFM81YmACUCwCBtgzC)

A little bit lengthy, but works nonetheless. I still can't fully understand how this even works (especially the counting duplicates section) and I'm on mobile, so explanations will be edited later.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 48 bytes

```sh
for n;A+=($@[(in:2:)$n]);<<<$@[`printf ${(o)A}`]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYq9DkAwFIV3T3GGDm0sWixUos8hEouG5RI/iRDPXpdJznK@75xzHYKX6op2WvsNDgco@GkBlS6upKgbOVJhCiWoVaW1lk03LyNtHuKSk3J314Y78jBIORo5DFPC7TUGGZv02zPmHDr8ng8)

Input is via argument array `$@`.
`A` is an array of indexes of secondary duplicates.
`printf ${(o)A}` sorts `A` leaving only the lowest index.
`<<<$@[ ]` prints the argument at that index.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 3 bytes (6 nibbles)

```
/-$`$$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWy_R1VRJUVCAcqNi2aKVoIx0FYzAy1FEw1VEwilWKhcoCAA)

Outputs `0` if there are no duplicated elements.

```
/-$`$$
 -      # remove
   `$   # unique elements of
     $  # input
  $     # from the input
        # (this leaves only duplicated elements,
        # in their original order);
/       # get the first element
        # (actually, fold returning left-hand element at each step,
        # but result is to return left-most element)
```

[5 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWK_WtdFUSVFR0DSF8qPDmaKVoIx0FEx0FYx0FUx0Fw1ilWKgUAA) to instead return `-1` when there are no duplicated elements, as in the example and initial spec:  `` /:-$`$$-1 ``

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom 96, bytes

```
g(a:List INT):INT==(for i in 2..#a repeat(for j in 1..i-1 repeat if a.i=a.j then return a.i);-1)
```

it is O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 54 bytes

```
a=>(b=[],a.find(e=>b.includes(e)?e:(b.push(e),0))||-1)
```

Uses another array to keep track of the already encountered values.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>65</s> 67 bytes

With thanks to LiefdeWen for the 89 bytes base code [here](https://tio.run/##lU9NS8QwED2bX/GOCdtd7KqntHsRPK0gePBQegg1rYHdSfNRRUp/e02XtZ59DMzMm/eYmSZsz5bsPARDHV6/Q9RnyVhzUiHgBSNDQogqmgaf1rzjWRniIfokr2oo3wVxVS14GqgpDMWqzpDSAW0iUGIVLFgbxmZVHsbWep7EcOWtdIXaHTV18UPCbTbid9anWV842SfOtFxVri5LVfW18DoOnrAw8lpvcznNN3Ld82gp2JPevXkT9dGQ5stZnPRXemHEPsPdJfIMDxn2mIT4j/n@Yk7O/M85sWn@AQ), here's an further shortened version of that

```
a=>{for(int p=0,q=0;;q++)for(p=0;p<q;)if(a[q]==a[p++])return a[q];}
```

We can dispense with the return -1 and length check as it's apparently OK to throw an exception if not found, so we just let the outer loop run off the end of the array. Some other whitespace changes, and jigging the declarations around to reduce the number of times we write "int" etc..

Comment: Pretty sure you can cut 1 char by making the second loop a while.


a=>{for(int p=0,q=0;;q++)while(p++<q)if(a[q]==a[p])return a[q];}

Comment: I checked, and it turns out, alas, it doesnt work out.. Doing `p++<q` means that although p is indeed incremented after the check of `p<q`, it is incremented before the inner loop code of `if(a[p]==a[q])`.. this has the undesirable effect of comparing `a[1]==a[1]` on the second iteration (q=1) which breaks the program. Still a useful comment though as it allowed me to chase down a bug (missing `p=0` on inner loop), that unfortunately added 3 bytes but I was able to save 1 by moving p++ to the if, thanks to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>115</s> 113 bytes

```python
a,i,k=input(),0,[]
while 1:
	if i==len(a):print-1;break
	elif a[i]not in k:k+=[a[i]]
	else:print a[i];break
	i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtLCoMwEEDX5hRZKk6hsa5S5iQhiwhTHBLGYCPi6dPa4vZ98lHmRYZaAzBEZMlbaTu4g/NqnzmRNlY1/NKMmEja0Nm8spSbeU4rhagaSl8bHHtZimbR0cYe3Qn8Kd/0H37J9XCPplZnYIAHjDD6Dw)

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't the fact that your list `k` can have up to `n` elements make this a `O(n)` space complexity solution?

Comment: Not to mention the fact that check `a[i] in k` may take `O(n)` (unless Python arrays is special)

Comment: @ValueInk you are correct. my bad.

Comment: This is actually **O(n log n)** in space complexity, because the numbers in your `k` take **O(log n)** memory to store each and there are as many as **n** of them.

Comment: I should think user202729 is correct too, making your algorithm O(n^2) time complexity. The while loop is O(n) (early break or not), and so is the `in` call.

Comment: @WheatWizard Wait what? Why the log n? k is filled with integers which are O(1) each, right? Their magnitude is not dependent on n.

Comment: @Sanchises The integers are dependent on **n**.  Since integers can always be as large as the length of the array, each will take (in the worst case) **O(log n)** bits to represent.  Meaning we have an array of length of up to **n** filled with items of up to **log n** bits.

Comment: @WheatWizard Ah yes, I didn't read that. But that means that we cannot even store one integer in O(1) extra space complexity, so I should think the author did not account for that when making the bonus.

Comment: @Sanchises You have a point, and I think you are probably correct however we should probably aim to be correct even if we think the author made a mistake. :)

Comment: Spaces, `print -1`=>`print-1`, `a[i] not in`=>`a[i]not in`.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
ε¹SsQƶ0K1è}W<¹sè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf8wNWFiMWX//861wrlTc1HGtjBLMcOofVc8wrlzw6j//zAxMjIwMTAwMDE5MzQ5MTA1MTk4NTAxNTkw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 + 2 (-ap) = 38 bytes

Runs in O(n) time.

```perl
$s{$_}=1while!$s{$_=shift@F};$_||=-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@luFolvtbWsDwjMydVEcyzLc7ITCtxcKu1VomvqbHVNfz/30jBRMFYwVTB3EzB9F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/uokFAA)

Takes the input list space separated.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes, O(n) time, O(n) memory

```python
a=input()
i=0
for x in a:
 if i&1<<x:print x;break
 i^=1<<x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERDkyvT1oArLb9IoUIhM08h0YpLITNNIVPN0MamwqqgKDOvRKHCOqkoNTEbKBFnCxL@/z/aSMcYCA11THWMYgE)

This does one pass of the list. Thus is **O(n)**  For memory it stores a integer `i`, which has bits representing which numbers have already been visited.  If a number has already been visited we output, otherwise we turn the bit on.  If no matches are found we do nothing.

This makes a slight improvement over the naïve way which requires copying the list at the cost of **O(n log n)** memory.

Comment: `i` needs to have `n` bits, so I think it should be `O(n)` memory. (`i` can take values up to `2**n - 2` even if there is a duplicate.)

Comment: However, it is better than a copy of the list, as a copy of the list in general needs `log(n)*n` bits if we are equally as strict (`log(n)` bits per item times `n` items).

Comment: @tehtmi Fixed now, thanks for that.  I have trouble with space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 98 bytes

**0-indexed**

Takes a space separated list of integers. returns `i < n` on a successful match and `i == n` on failure.

time complexity is O(n^2) yuck!

space complexity is O(1)

```
program-name.exe 58 77 57 7 75 44 29 97 92 59 36 52 95 87 44 24 47 18 34 22
Returns 14  (the two 44s)
```

Golfed

```c
i=1,j;main(int c,char**v){for(;i<c;i++)for(j=i-1;j;j--)if(!strcmp(v[i],v[j]))goto f;f:return i-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBDoIwFAWvgrsW6ILSWmrlJIQFaaz@JoCplY3x7E8wbzOTeV7cvQeob@ro5okWRksufO0fUyrLjX/Cmpijq3dUVfyQ2JNoXHRRCE6BnV45@fnJtoHGehviyPl9zWsRXLikW36npTj@XwC6gzHQBvs0lIK0sAZWQlu0Z2gJq9GZf1JQBk2Hdmf5Aw)

Ungolfed

```c
i=1,j;
main(int c, char**v){
    for(;i < c; i++)
        for(j=i-1; j; j--)
            if(!strcmp(v[i], v[j]))
                goto f;
    f:
    return i-1;
}
```

Comment: Time complexity is related to looping.  A loop that touches every slot of an array with size `n` is said to have time complexity `O(n)`.  Since you have a `for` loop inside another one, and each one is on the order `O(n)` (since they aren't always a constant range), your program has time complexity `O(n^2)`.  For more info about Big O Notation, check out [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. I updated my answer.

Comment: The time complexity should be `O(n^2 log m)`, where `n` is how many numbers there are, and `m` is the largest number given. This is because `strcmp` takes linear time with respect to the number of characters in each string

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 93 bytes

```powershell
$c=0..$a.Count;$i=0;$r=($a|%{$i++;if($c[$_]++ -ne $_){$i}});if($r.Count -gt 0){$r[0]}else{-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctLCoMwFEbhrdzBX1DyIFo6Chl1GSIS5LYNBC1R6cBm7alYOLOP854/nJYXx1jgXSvpetZIuklqC0ZntIbX93mbVovgjEVyFfz3siMIYcOjwthh6IUgNTFhqA/IuT4l/UdSz5XMAakzfea48K6aXMoP)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 81 bytes

Time complexity is O(n) !!!!

Space complexity is O(1) !!!!

```javascript
a=>a.reduce((r,e,i)=>r?r:(a[(e<0?~e:e)-1]>0?((a[(e<0?~e:e)-1]^=-1)?0:0):i+2),0)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XchBCsMgEADAr3jcpWtQSy9S9SEhBTGbYpEYTNpjv25Lj4U5zSO@4p5a3g651pl74UMswvXofBwaz8/EAI2YMjrfQrMQR@CrCm@2jFJPXgX4v5uTGoOyCm0@GST1zZ7qutfCQ6l3WGA0JM4/msSFhJkQ@wc)

Strategy

This algorithm leverages the fact that indexes are positive but numbers in javascript are signed.  Also, zeros are not allowed input.  As long as the array is not longer than 2^31, this solution will work. I double the use of the original array as my lookup array -- marking a visited number by switching the value at that index with its 2's compliment.

Comment: We've had this discussion on another answer using a similar algorithm.  Although it may appear that this is O(1) you are actually using O(n) memory.  Since you use the sign bit of each number you are actually using 1 bit per number.  The fact that the bits are already allocated by Javascript is just a trick to make it appear as if you are using less memory.

Comment: I don't think you are being intentionally deceitful here, the concept of additional memory that seems to be embedded in the question is rather flawed.  O(n) memory is required just to store the array already unless you are using a stream so any algorithm that stores the entire list in memory at any point is truly O(n log n) anyway (log n because each number takes at most log n bits to store).

Comment: @WheatWizard Wouldn't it be O(n log m) since n (the number of inputs) and m (the largest integer) are independent of one another? Though I usually assume integers are a fixed width (more background in Java/C++/C than Python/Javascript) which means their storage is O(1)

Comment: @WheatWizard, I see your point. Like you said, the question wording is a bit open. However, I think this is a legitimate solution. No other solution makes any attempt to use fewer bits to store each number. The parameters were for O(1) _additional_ space complexity and the array can _only_ contain numbers between 1 and `a.len`.  It is worded like a homework question begging for such a solution. You are correct about O(n log n) initial space complexity _if_ you assume that storage space per number is not fixed. This is seldom an assumption and I don't think it was implied in this competition.

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS 52 char 104 bytes

```
f←{1≠⍴⍴⍵:¯1⋄v←(⍵⍳⍵)-⍳⍴⍵⋄m←v⍳(v<0)/v⋄m≡⍬:¯1⋄(1⌷m)⌷⍵}
```

comments (for me f could return results even for vectors of characters that here seems to be the old strings)

```
1≠⍴⍴⍵:¯1     if ⍵ has rank different from 1 than it is not a vector so return -1
v←(⍵⍳⍵)-⍳⍴⍵   v is 0 0 0...0 only if there are not repetitions, else there is some value <0
m←v⍳(v<0)/v   m return the indices j of v where v[j]<0, and so ⍵[j] are all the duplicates
m≡⍬:¯1       if m is void than that index not exist, so no duplicate and return -1
(1⌷m)⌷⍵      else return the value in ⍵ of the first element of m
```

results

```
  f 1
¯1
  f 1,2,3,4
¯1
  f 1 2 3 3
3
  f 2 3 3 1 5 2
3
  f ,1
¯1
```

Comment: It's possible to use Dyalog's codepage to make it so it's 52 *bytes*. Also, you don't need to store the results in a function. And would either of these work in NARS? `{1≠⍴⍴⍵:¯1⋄⍬≡m←v⍳v/⍨0>v←(⍵⍳⍵)-⍳⍴⍵:¯1⋄⍵⌷⍨1⌷m}` or `{1≠⍴⍴⍵:¯1⋄⍬≡m←v⍳(0>v)/v←(⍵⍳⍵)-⍳⍴⍵:¯1⋄(1⌷m)⌷⍵}`?

Comment: @Zacharý I like "f←{1≠⍴⍴⍵:¯1⋄⍬≡m←v⍳(0>v)/v←(⍵⍳⍵)-⍳⍴⍵:¯1⋄(1⌷m)⌷⍵}" thank you; for what regard if the name of function I ' am not agree with community, for me the name has to be inside the solution, it will for me 2 characters more (or +4 bytes). It seems my target is not 100% codegolf, perhaps 80% . It would be better for a solution in APL count for codegolf it would be in characters and not in bytes

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 47 bytes

```
f=lambda l,i=0:l[i]if l[i]in l[:i]else f(l,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LDoIwEEXX9CtmSeMsLAUfJCxd@A21C9Q2NtRCShfw9XUwJm7m3pNzk5nW9BqDzLa7Zd@/788ePLpu33rltLPwjUDROm38bMCW5HeCZztGGICcYkpghRJrbFBoZGqDI@EB6w1/dqsSTyiIK9nUEs@a6ZYVKa50iym6kEpbDpyzwiwPMyW4hqdZLjHSr34G858Znj8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 69 bytes

```
D,k,@@*,BF€=B]ßEB*MVcGA$p
D,w,@@,BF€=s1<
D,l,@~,$
L~,AÞwB]dVbUG€k»lbU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ1vHwUFLx8ntUdMaW6fYw/NdnbR8w5LdHVUKuFx0yoGSULliQxugQI6OQ52OCpdPnY7j4XnlTrEpYUmh7kDp7EO7c5JCgcal6zhY6RjGcnGppNtFGyoYKRgqGAOxUSwnJ6e1giFcGCQBlIIIG8GFjWGCcMUgMZCoKRBCTTFGUo5kOEwYKoBinbGCCVC/mYK5goWCpYKhgYIhUJ0RmDSIBamEWWYCVGqqYAg1wLWoKL/oPwA)

### How it works

Oddly enough, despite Add++ having a [deduplicate command](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus/blob/master/add%2B%2B.py#L744), this doesn't use it. This exits with an error code of **1** when there is no duplicated element.

We start by removing any elements without more than one occurrence, in order to leave the stack with an array containing the original array, preserving order, without any elements which only occur once. This is done by the use of filtering by the dyadic function **w**:

```
D,w,@@,BF€=s1<
L~,AÞw
```

Here, the lambda is implicitly called with the argument. The `~` tells it to unpack its argument to the stack beforehand, then the `A` pushes the argument to the stack. Thesefore, if the input looks like `[a b c a c]`, the stack would look like

```
[a b c a c [a b c a c]]
```

We want this structure, called **dyad-binding**, due to the way the **filter-keep** quick, `Þ`, works in regard to non-monadic arguments. Here, its functional argument is **w**, a dyadic (two argument) function. This means that, instead of filtering over each element in the stack using **w**, it pops the top element of the stack, the list `[a b c a c]` in this case, and uses that as the right argument when filtering every other element.

So, for one iteration of **w**, the stack may look like this at the start of execution:

```
[[a b c a c] a]
```

Then `BF` flattens the stack, and then we come to another dyadic quick: `€`. Again, the popping behaviour is simulated, and `a` is used as the left argument to the succeeding function, the equality operator in this case. This compares `a` with the elements of `[a b c a c]`, yielding an array of **1**s and **0**s. By now, the stack looks something like this

```
[1 0 0 1 0]
```

Finally, `s` takes the sum, and `1<` asserts that it is greater than **1**. This essentailly counts the occurences of each element of the input in the input itself, and removes them if the count is only **1** i.e. the element isn't duplicated at some point.

After applying `Þw` to the input, the stack results in

```
[a c a c]
```

We'll call this array **A**. The rest of the code is determining which of these remaining elements occurs for the second time first i.e. the actual task in the challenge.

Next, we want to perform **k** over the remaining list. In order to do this, with **k** being dyadic and taking **A** as its left argument. Again, we want to create the dyad-binding structure, but using the elements of **A** instead of the arguments. In a general case, if the stack looks like `[a b c d e]`, where `a - e` are arbitrary pieces of data, the following code will convert that into a dyad-binding structure:

```
B]dVbUG
```

So, this makes our stack look like `[a c a c [a c a c]]`, before calling **k** over `€`ach of the elements, using the array as the left argument.

```
D,k,@@*,BF€=B]ßEB*MVcGA$p
```

**k** is our main function to isolate the first deduplicated element. Here, we have our two arguments, **I**, the element in the array being iterated over, and **A**, our array containing the elements that occur more than once. The first part of the code, `BF€=`, identifies which elements of **A** are equal to **I**. Now, we generate the *truthy* indices - the indices of elements in **A** that are equal to **I**. There is a bug in `ßE`, causing it to start from **0** (corrected after the challenge was posted). However, as this means the first occurence if **I** will always be set to **0** because of this bug, and the offset of **1** doesn't change between elements, this means that we can avoid the lengthier `dbLBc` which is bug free. Let's use `a` as an example value for **I**. Now, our stack resembles

```
[[0 1] [1 0] [2 1] [3 0]]
```

The first element is the 0-based index **i**, the second whether or not **I = A[i]**. Next, we remove the indexes where **I ≠ A[i]**, by taking the product of each pair with `B*`, then taking the maximum value with `MVcG`. Finally, we push **I** to the stack and pair them as a list. With **I** as `a`, the final value returned is:

```
[2 a]
```

This process happens over each element of **A**, eventually leading to a series of paired lists of the highest index of the element of **A** in **A** itself. Finally we want to find the element which has the *lowest* first element, the element whose duplcicate appears first. Here, as Add++ doesn't have a builtin to get the first or last element of a list, we use our third helper function **l**:

```
D,l,@~,$
L~,…»l…
```

While Add++ doesn't have a builtin for head of an array, it does have a **minimum-by** quick, `»`. We take the list which has the minimum return value when passed through the function **l**. This helper function unpacks its argument to the stack before performing any commands with the `~` command, then `$` swaps them, so the index comes first and is the value returned. Essentially, we return the element with the smallest duplicated element.

Unfortunately, this returns the entire array, both the index and the element, rather than just the element, so we append a `bU` to unpack this array to the stack, returning only the last element of the pair - the first duplicated element.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
g;main(i){scanf("%d",&i);return i[&g]++?i:main();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrBCsIwEAV/JRQsDdVDN1k3MQc/RDyUqGEP5lD1VPrtz1DmMjCTTyVnoKT3rHVQu37yXF9Dd3h0x15tWp7f31KN3vpyH8erXvbPpg0g4xqTYUPgABGwoMHwHhQRBbGVCHcGEyIjyJ48vGAKcM3pDw)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

```c
g;main(i){for(;scanf("%d",&i),i[&g]^=1;);return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcnBCgIhFEbhV5GBBoVp4dXbVaQniYLBGnGRgdUqevY/iW9z4OR9yRko6b7Wpqv5bI@u0zOvbdPT7jotczVLPc3lfDnaZFK/vd69qZq@ACk3WMWKwAEiYMHA8B4UEQVxnAh3ABMiI8h/eXiBDXCj6Qc)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes

```c
g;main(i){scanf("%d",&i);i[&g]++?printf("%d",i):main();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCsIwEEWvEgqWhuqiScbJmIUHERclYpiFoai70rN/Q5G3efz386nkDJT0mrUOatdPnutz6A6P7tirTXrry30cr8tb6/e/q73sb5s2wBnfmAwZB4pgBjEahBDgBMKQVgT@DHIQQuQ9BQTGFOGbux8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-æ`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
VaWbU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LeY&code=VmFXYlU&input=WzIsIDMsIDMsIDEsIDUsIDJd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
Tg@iNgHiUig@i
```

Takes the numbers as separate command-line arguments. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's a 15-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/JN0h0y/dwSZTWzsTyPz//7/Rf2MgNPxv@t8IAA)

#### Explanation

```
               g is list of cmdline args; i is 0 (implicit)
T              Loop till
 g@i           the i'th element of g (0-indexed)
    N          is in
     gHi       the first i elements of g:
        Ui      Increment i
          g@i  Return the i'th element of g
```

This outputs the first duplicate or, if there are no duplicates, the first number in the list (because the indexing wraps around).

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 32 bytes

```
Prompt A
Repeat 2=Ans(I
I+1→I
cumSum(ʟA=ʟA(I
End
ʟA(I
```

needs a fresh interpreter or `I` initialized to `0`. Will error if there is no duplicates

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.find(z=>(x[~z]+={})[25])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q5CLy0zL0WjytZOoyK6ripW27a6VjPayDRW8781V3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RppGtJGOgrGOgiGYNNVRMIrV1PwPAA)

No effort on bonus at all

-1 from SuperStormer

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q5CLy0zL0WjytZOoyK6ripW27a6VjPayDRW8781V3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RppGtJGOgrGOgiGYNNVRMIrV1PwPAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 97 bytes, \$O(n)\$ time, \$O(n)\$ space

```go
func (l[]int)int{m:=make(map[int]int)
for i,e:=range l{if _,o:=m[e];o{return e}
m[e]=i}
return-1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY5BCoMwEEX3OcXQVQKxoG2hWHKHLroTKUESCZpEQuwmeJJupNBDeZvG6LIww_A_j__n_WntvMDAm463AjRXBik9WOePB6n9Ab24A8m-o5fZdeFyNA3gvqqV8SRu0CXTvBNY86GKOvlIWgeKipI5bmJoH5SEJ7URrUR9s8EJPzoDYkKrwdSENifLp73okYrWbzCBgO4u5vYGS5yaQ0HhlCancKFQTIT8Y86JiUC-Anv2PG_3Bw)

Goes over the input slice exactly once per element. The map stores a pair per element, meaning \$O(n)\$ space as well.

Answer (score 0):

## [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 48 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Where((_,i)=>x[..i].Contains(x[i])).First()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFLa8MwDMfPzacQPdngGdLHKUthbHSwBwwK6yELwzhuJ3AdZrtbSulnz5Rsh@7RWTZG1k9/2bIOZzrodhvQrWGxC9FssuTYk3foXn8cXdbWGh2xduF0RF4bZzzqLNFWhQAPvl57tYF9MghRRdTwVmMF9wodC9GTSFGC8uvAO2S@dfocXSxKAbTNYAU5tE0@a@TyxXjD2LNATm4hJZZU10USCqwpsORcztGHyHg7yJIr7O@j/O6bXjQhkqQz7/CL6ADGs6Rj5EVVsY7qQ7CHkYBxP1MBUwEjOJB3Ck5FKkZkxKSnmLEg@19kIqa0UjElbEIYPTfU1silx2jog8xXB@VNTd0cPrmh6B8oF6b7DkZ9W7FG3podp/FX/mdha4/RPG/ko7Jb06UMDsmh/QA)

#### Alternative without LINQ, 58 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int i=0;;)if(x[..++i].Contains(x[i]))return x[i];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFLSwMxEMfP3U8x9LRLY3D7OMUtiKLgAwRBD3UPIU3LQJpgktWWsp99nawe6qNmEsLM/OafZKLCiQqqawLaNTzuQtQbkR16/A7t64/QhTNGq4jOhuMZfq2t9qhEpowMAR68W3u5gX02CFFGVPDmcAn3Em0eoieRRQ3Sr0ORkKvGqjO0cVEzoG0OK6ig21bz/cr5nCKA1akQBa7y7YLz0QhrOtxGUgsUwboovI6Nt5Ac0XYDkV1ifzPpd9@Uow6RxK1@h19EAvJCZInh58tlnqg@BXsYM5j0s2QwYzCGlrxjcMlKNiYjpjzGTBjZ/yJTNqNVshlhU8LozcEZzZ89Rk1fpb96yW8c9XX4YoesfyB/1OljcuogdYzf6l1B46/6z4ONOUSrasufpGl0Khm0Wdt9AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 38 bytes

```arturo
$->a[0-1select.n:1a=>[in?&take a<=1+]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Wps1yb)

```
$->a[              ; a function taking an arg a
    0-1            ; push -1
    select.n:1a=>[ ; select the first elt in a that
        in?&       ; is the current elt in
        <=1+       ; increment stack and duplicate
        take a     ; take that many of the first elts in a
    ]              ; end select
]                  ; end function
```